# Using while/read/do to pass the content of file as the argument of a command

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop

I'm really new to Linux scripting. I am sure this is simple, but I cannot figure it out.
As part of a script, I am trying to pass the content of a file as arguments of a command in a script:

```
while read i 

do $COMMAND $i 

done < file.lst
```

I want to pass every line of the *file.lst* as the argument of the *command* except the very first line of the file. How to I do this?

EDIT:

Here is the section of the script:

```
while read i 
do cp --recursive --preserve=all $i $DIR
done < $DIR/file.lst
```

Comment: add this `< awk 'NR>1' file.lst` after `done`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks for that. For some reason I get *Syntax error near unexpected token `'NR>1''* :P

Comment: In your file `file.lst`, does every line correspond to just one file to copy, or can you have several files on one line, separated by spaces?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf just one file per line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read -r i
do
  "$COMMAND" "$i"
done < <(sed -n '2,$p' file.lst)
```

Comment: Thanks, I still get the same error For some reason *Syntax error near unexpected token `(sed -n '2,$p' file.lst)'* I have edited the question could you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @user2617731 there was a `<` missing. I fixed that for you.

Answer (score 0):

This solutions does not use a while so I am not entirely sure if it solves your problem, but based on your code sample. you can do the following

```
tail -n +2 input | xargs echo
```

This will read all lines from input starting at line 2 and execute echo using the value of the line

the file input contains:

```
skip
1
2
3
```

executing that command gives

```
1
2
3
```

Just substitute input for the file you want and echo for the command you want

Comment: you can even use the -P option with xargs and execute the processes in parallel

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra `read` to consume the first line before the `while` loop begins.

```
{
    read -r;
    while read -r i; do
        "$COMMAND" "$i"
    done
} < file.lst
```